# Why am I getting NaN as a computed result? (Piecewise Linear Interpolation with Lagrange Standard Form)

Tags: c++, interpolation

I am writing a program that will utilize Lagrange Standard Form in a Piecewise Linear fashion to interpolate a polynomial of degree n. I have the code working properly for the first subinterval and the third and fourth subintervals, but, for some reason that I cannot figure, I am receiving NaN as the output for my second subinterval. The second subinterval is calculated beneath the line commented //P2. I have racked my brain and tried every alteration I could think of to fix the problem, but have had no luck. If anyone could provide some insight I would be greatly appreciative. Note that I only included code up to the second interpolating polynomial as the third and fourth follow in similar fashion. I apologize in advance for the brutality of my code. I am relatively new to C++ and have not had time to acquire the elegance that would probably be expected for a problem of this magnitude. Thanks again.

```
ofstream Outfile;
Outfile.open ("PiecewiseLagrange_D.dat");
double *P1 = new double[201]; //Polynomial 1
double *P2 = new double[201]; //Polynomial 2
double *P3 = new double[201]; //Polynomial 3
double *P4 = new double[201]; //Polynomial 4
double *x = new double[201]; //Interpolating points/x's
double *x1 = new double[(int)n+1]; //First subinterval/mesh/xi's
double *x2 = new double[(int)n+1]; //Second subinterval
double *x3 = new double[(int)n+1]; //Third subinterval
double *x4 = new double[(int)n+1]; //Fourth subinterval
double a, b; //interval end points
char func; //function selection
double xDifference1;
double xDifference2;

cout << "Enter an interval with integer end points (lesser value first)";
cin >> a >> b;

for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) //Initialize
{
    P1[i] = 0;
    P2[i] = 0;
    P3[i] = 0;
    P4[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    x1[i] = 0;
    x2[i] = 0;
    x3[i] = 0;
    x4[i] = 0;
}


x1[0] = a;
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    x1[i] = x1[0] + i*(((b-a)/4)/n);
    cout << x1[i] << endl;
}
cout << endl;
x2[0] = x1[(int) n];
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    x2[i] = x2[0] + i*(((b-a)/4)/n);
    cout << x2[i] << endl;
}
cout << endl;
x3[0] = x2[(int) n];
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    x3[i] = x3[0] + i*(((b-a)/4)/n);
    cout << x3[i] << endl;
}
cout << endl;
x4[0] = x3[(int) n];
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    x4[i] = x4[0] + i*(((b-a)/4)/n);
    cout << x4[i] << endl;
}


cout << "Enter a function to evaluate (1,2, or 3):";
cin >> func;
//cout << "Polynomial is g1(x) on [" << a << "," << b << "]" << endl;

if (func == '1')
{
    //P1
    x[0] = a;
    for (int i=0; i<=200; i++)
    {
        x[i] = x[0] + i*((x1[(int) n] - x1[0])/200);
    }

    for (int j=0; j<=200; j++)
    {
        xDifference1 = 0;
        xDifference2 = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
        {
            xDifference1 = (x1[i] - x1[i+1]);
            xDifference2 = (x1[i+1] - x1[i]);

            P1[j] = F1(x1[i])*((x[j] - x1[i+1])/xDifference1) + F1(x1[i+1])*((x[j] - x1[i])/xDifference2);
        }

        Outfile << x[j] << "      " << P1[j] << "     " << F1(x[j]) << endl;
        cout << setw(8) << x[j] << setw(12) << P1[j] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;


    //P2
    x[0] = x1[(int) n];
    for (int i=0; i<=200; i++)
    {
        x[i] = x[0] + i*((x2[(int) n] - x2[0])/200);
    }

    for (int j=0; j<=200; j++)
    {
        xDifference1 = 0;
        xDifference2 = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
        {
            xDifference1 = (x2[i] - x2[i+1]);
            xDifference2 = (x2[i+1] - x2[i]);

            P2[j] = F1(x2[i])*((x[j] - x2[i+1])/xDifference1) + F1(x2[i+1])*((x[j] - x2[i])/xDifference2);
        }

        Outfile << x[j] << "      " << P2[j] << "     " << F1(x[j]) << endl;
        cout << setw(8) << x[j] << setw(12) << P2[j] << "      " << F1(x[j]) << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
```

Comment: I suppose I should mention that the function F1( ) simply returns the absolute value of its parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not calling any other functions, you'll get a NaN when you divide zero by zero (`0.0 / 0.0`).  At some point your `xDifference1` and/or `xDifference2` are zero.

Dividing a non-zero by zero gives an infinity.

**Edit** However, as that's apparently not the case further investigation shows that the various `x` arrays, including `x2`, have `n+1` elements in them, indexed `0` thru `n`.  During your loop, you access `x2[i+1]`.  Since `i` will equal `n` on the last iteration, you access element `x2[n+1]` which is out of bounds of the array and results in undefined behavior.  In this case, the random memory right after the array generates a NaN for `x2` but not the other arrays.

In an unrelated note, you your inner `i` loops you assign to `P2[j]` for every iteration, so the only value you get out of the loops is from the last iteration.  Did you mean to use `P2[j] += ...`?

Comment: I did cout all of my xDifferences to check for that and they stay constant at -0.025 and 0.025 so there should be no division by zero

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so much. And to the unrelated note, no, but my implementation was wrong. I had forgotten to impose conditions and I should've been storing values outside of the i loops. Thank you for pointing that out as well. +1 if I could.